# Equation not showing up in Canvas

Tags: python, function, canvas, tkinter, equation

Hey guys I am trying to write a code for a small program and everything works fine but I can't get my whole math equation (C = A + B) or any of its variants to show up in Canvas. here is my code below, any help would be appreciated. The user inputs their first number, then inputs the operator (+, -, *, /) then a second number and then the "Addition Result, Subtraction Result, Multiplication Result, or Division Result" shows up in text along with the numbers, operator, and resulting answer generated. My "results" text shows up but the equation does not, for example, if I enter 60 + 5 as my numbers and operator the Canvas displays only "Addition Result" where I want it but not 60 + 5 = 65. This is where I need help!

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
canvas_width = 400
canvas_height = 400

w = Canvas (master, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, bg = "blue")
w.pack()

A = int(input("Enter the First Operand: "))
O = (input("Enter the Operator: "))
B = int(input("Enter the Second Operand: "))

#If Functions for Math
def Add(A, B):
    return A + B
def Subtract(A, B):
    return A - B
def Multiply(A, B):
    return A * B
def Divide(A, B):
    return A / B



if (O == "+"):
    Add(A, B)
elif (O == "-"):
    Subtract(A, B)
elif (O == "*"):
    Multiply(A, B)
else:
    if (O == "/"):
        Divide(A, B)



#If Functions for Formula
if (O == "+"):
    D = Add(A, B)
elif (O == "-"):
    D = Subtract(A, B)
elif (O == "*"):
    D = Multiply(A, B)
else:
    if (O == "/"):
        D = Divide(A, B)



#If Functions for Result text
if (O == "+"):
     w.create_text(canvas_width / 3, canvas_height / 3, font=("Arial", 14), text="Addition Result", fill="white")
elif (O == "-"):
     w.create_text(canvas_width / 3, canvas_height / 3, font=("Arial", 14), text="Subtraction Result", fill="white")
elif (O == "*"):
     w.create_text(canvas_width / 3, canvas_height / 3, font=("Arial", 14), text="Multiplication Result", fill="white")
else:
    if (O == "/"):
         w.create_text(canvas_width / 3, canvas_height / 3, font=("Arial", 14), text="Division Result", fill="white")


#If Functions for Formula Text
if (O == "+"):
    w.create_text(canvas_width / 2, canvas_height / 2, font=("Arial", 18), text=D, fill="white")
elif (O == "-"):
    w.create_text(canvas_width / 2, canvas_height / 2, font=("Arial", 18), text=D, fill="white")
elif (O == "*"):
    w.create_text(canvas_width / 2, canvas_height / 2, font=("Arial", 18), text=D, fill="white")
else:
    if (O == "/"):
        w.create_text(canvas_width / 2, canvas_height / 2, font=("Arial", 18), text=D, fill="white")
```

Comment: I have changed the code to what I currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions `Add`, `Subtract`, `Multiply`, `Divide` don't return anything, so when you call `D = Add(1 + 1)`, D is None. So just put `return` instead of `C =`:

```
def Add(A, B):
    return A + B
def Subtract(A, B):
    return A - B
def Multiply(A, B):
    return A * B
def Divide(A, B):
    return A / B
```

EDIT: If you wont it to say for example "1 + 1 = 2", replace `text = D` to `text = "{} {} {} = {}".format(A, O, B, D)`

Comment: Thank you! So how would I assign a variable to that so that I can have the equation (A + B = C) show up in canvas? As in say the numbers entered were 60 + 5, so on Canvas it would show "60 + 5 = 65"

Comment: Is there a way to do that without using these {}? I havent quite covered the use of using those yet in my class but I am very thankful for all the info you've provided so far :D

Comment: Of course. You can type: `text = str(A) + O + str(B) + "=" + str(D)`.